# How to properly initialize a python queue?

Tags: python, queue

I'm new to python and having trouble with the python queue, I'm initializing queue in my init constructor by when I run my python app it crashes, I've included a snippet of my code is there a better way to do it?

```
import os, sys
import time
if(sys.hexversion < 0x03000000):
  import Queue
else:
  import queue as Queue

class Appwindow():
  def __init__(self):
     self.myQueue = Queue.Queue()

  def displayMeth(self, stuff):
      if self.displayed:
         self.myQueue.put(stuff)
```

Comment: I ran your code and it didn't crash. [mcve] please.

Comment: Here, also: your code completes without problem on Python2.7 installed on CentOS.

Comment: Thanks,I must be doing something else wrong

Answer (score 1):

```
try:
    from queue import Queue
except ImportError:
    from Queue import Queue

# shiny fancy Atomic Message Queue for concurrency
q = Queue()
```